# Does GitLab support assigning a reviewer based on the contributor?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, code-review

My company has the notion of a Senior Tier of developers. These developers are dispersed amongst development teams. Then we assign the Senior Developers from one team to assess the contribution from a different team they were assigned.

Let's say I have a project `foo` and for `foo`, I want

- `SeniorBarGroup` to review PRs to `BazGroup`, and
- `SeniorBazGroup` to review PRs to `QuzGroup`

Is this workflow possible in GitLab?

Comment: What about CO - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/code_owners.html

Comment: @Kyslik Right from the get go, that doesn't sound like what I want (I may be missing something). _"Code Owners define who owns specific files or directories in a repository."_. That's what everyone does. We don't have "code owners" at $work though. We have team owners. Two senior devs owns the contributions of another team, regardless of files or directories.

Comment: I think neither GH or GL support what you want. Even if you automate and "request" review from correct teams (using API or GraphQL), GL won't enforce it the same way how CO works.

Comment: According to this [source](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16177/does-gitlab-support-assigning-a-reviewer-based-on-the-contributor), there is no native functionality in GitLab to help assist in assigning a reviewer based on the contributor. However, you can model this relationship external to GitLab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any native functionality to help assist in this, and that this relationship will have to be modeled external to GitLab. I've opened this issue for clarity,

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/365887